# WordPress 301 MASS redirect all tags to their parent post

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

My WordPress link structure is custom: /%postname%.html

My Webserver is: Apache

In the past I used tags till I realized that for my niche is a bad SEO practice because here tags basically create duplicate content(Are OK to use tags if them are repeat and are interconnected).

I've set to no index tags but Google continue to index old tags(declared before no index).

**I want** to mass 301 redirect through **htaccess** all my tags to their parent post, now I redirect tags via htaccess to the main domain with:

```
# Redirect tag 301
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^tag/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: What is the actual problem here?

Comment: I want to 301 redirect through htaccess all my WordPress tags to their parent post.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't not explain the problem. You need to be clearer about what you *want to achieve*, what you *have tried* to do to achieve it, what output you are *expecting*, and what output you are *getting instead*. In it's current state, your question is not clear, and so you won't be able to get help until it is.